# average ingredients for each drug in each year for a specific manufacturer

Tags: openfda, programming, python

I want to count the average number of ingredients in each drug produced by a specific manufacturer in each year.

The results I want should be like this:

```
year | drug_names | avg_number_of_ingredients

2018 | drugA,drugB | 21
```

Can someone please help.

**What I have done so far?**
I have tried different queries here : https://open.fda.gov/apis/drug/label/example-api-queries/
but unfortunately, the maximum I can do is count some field following some conditions like the query below:

> `https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=effective_time:[20110601+TO+20121231]&count=openfda.brand_name.exact&limit=1`

What I want is to group manufacturers and count their drugs per year.

Thanks.

Comment: @JanDoggen I have updated the question.